# Getting Unexpected Result in For Loop

Tags: php, for-loop

### I have this function ...

```
public function getGroupName($no_of_participant) {
        $groupNameArry = array();
        $groupNumber = 0;

        for($i = 0; $i <= $no_of_participant/2; $i++) { // loop for rows
            for($letter = 'A'; $letter <= 'Z'; $letter++) {  // loop for columns
                if($groupNumber <= $no_of_participant/2) {
                    if($i == 0) {
                        $groupNameArry[$groupNumber] = $letter;
                    } else {
                        $groupNameArry[$groupNumber] = $letter.$i;
                    }

                    $groupNumber++;
                }
            }
        }

        return $groupNameArry;
    }
```

### The expected Result is

```
A-Z and then A1,B1,C1,D1 ....
```

### But unexpectedly getting

```
A-Z and then AA, AB, AC ...
```

I am calling this function like as

```
$groupNameArry = $this->getGroupName(MAX_ALLOWED_PARTICIPANT);
```

where maximum allowed participant value is 100. what is wrong? Please help!

Comment: your code more looks like it should return A, B1, C2, D3

Comment: try `range('A', 'Z');` array for your letter loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$letter` is a string.

When `$letter` becomes `'Z'`, the condition `$letter <= 'Z'` is `TRUE` and it runs what you expect to be the last iteration.

After this iteration `$letter++` increments `'Z'` and it becomes `'AA'`. This is how PHP handles `++` on strings.

The increment operator turning `'Z'` into `'AA'` is even given as example in the documentation of the [increment operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) (See Example #1).

Then the condition `$letter <= 'Z'` is still `TRUE` and it runs more iterations with `$letter` having the values `'AA'`, `'AB'`, `'AC'` a.s.o.

**The PHP way** to iterate from `'A'` to `'Z'` is to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on a [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    echo($letter);
}
echo("\nDone.");
```

The [output](https://3v4l.org/1fb8X) is:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

In you code `$i = 0` in every loop !!

This fixes your issue.

```
 /**
 * Get group name
 * 
 * @param int $no_of_participant
 * @return string
 */
public static function getGroupName(int $no_of_participant)
{
    $groupNameArry = array();
    $groupNumber = 0;

    $letters = range('A', 'Z');

    foreach ($letters as $letter) {

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $no_of_participant / 2; $i++) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $groupNameArry[$groupNumber] = $letter;
            } else {
                $groupNameArry[$groupNumber] = $letter . $i;
            }
            $groupNumber++;
        }
    }

    return $groupNameArry;
}
```